# How to insert a child subelement in Python ElementTree

Tags: python

My xml :-

```
<users>
</users>
```

i need to just append a child element :-

```
<users>
<user name="blabla" age="blabla" ><group>blabla</group>
</users>
```

My code giving some error :(

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
doc = ET.parse("users.xml")
root_node = doc.find("users")
child = ET.SubElement(root_node, "user")
child.set("username","srquery")
group  = ET.SubElement(child,"group")
group.text = "fresher"
tree = ET.ElementTree(root_node)
tree.write("users.xml")
```

I missed out "append" , but i don't have idea where to add that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line

```
root_node = doc.find("users")
```

...to this line

```
root_node = doc.getroot()
```

The key takeaway here is that `doc` is already a reference to the root node, and is accessed with `getroot()`. `doc.find('users')` will not return anything, since `users` is not a child of the root, it's the root itself.

Comment: oooyi :) my mistake, Thanks for your time Triptych. God bless you.

Answer (score 2):

A slightlly modified version to explain what happens:

```
root = ET.fromstring('<users></users>') # same as your doc=ET.parse(...).find(...), btw. doc=root
el = ET.Element('group')   # creating a new element/xml-node
root.append(el)            # and adding it to the root

ET.tostring(root)
>>> '<users><group /></users>'
el.text = "fresher"        # adding your text
ET.tostring(root)
>>>  '<users><group>fresher</group></users>'
```