# Adding new SubElement into existing XML file using ElementTree

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, elementtree

I have two folders in which one folder contains thousands of images and another folder has corresponding .xml files. XML file and image names are same (i.e. 2007.xml and 2007.jpg).
Now i would like to add image name (2007.jpg) into their corresponding file (2007.xml). 
.xml file format is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ASCII'?>
<annotation>
  <size>
    <width>1820</width>
    <height>940</height>
  </size>
  <object>
    <name>Car</name>
    <bndbox>
      <xmin>74.0</xmin>
      <ymin>509.0</ymin>
      <xmax>236.0</xmax>
      <ymax>609.0</ymax>
    </bndbox>
</annotation>
```

i want to add new SubElement

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ASCII'?>
    <annotation>
      <filename>2007.jpg</filename>
      <size>
        <width>1820</width>
        <height>940</height>
      </size>
      <object>
        <name>Car</name>
        <bndbox>
          <xmin>74.0</xmin>
          <ymin>509.0</ymin>
          <xmax>236.0</xmax>
          <ymax>609.0</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </annotation>
```

I am trying this way:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os
doc = ET.parse('00390.xml')
root = doc.getroot()
s = '/image/00390.jpg'
filename = (os.path.basename(s))
userElement = ET.Element("annotation")
newSub = ET.SubElement(userElement, "filename")
newSub.set(filename, '')
root.insert(0, newSub)
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write(open('3.xml', 'w'), encoding = 'UTF-8')
```

Output is received: `<filename 00390.jpg=""/>`
Although output should be `<filename>00390.jpg</filename>` 
I think issue is using newSub.set() which takes 3 input argument.

Comment: when i tried to add its always added in the last (just before </annotation>)

Comment: You should be able to use `insert()` which takes an index: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.insert. Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25824920/407651

Comment: mzjn i have added my code into question, please let me know where i am doing wrong?

Comment: @Sanjay feel free to accept either of the answers that has solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated answer for your new problem**

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os
doc = ET.parse('00390.xml')
root = doc.getroot()
s = '/image/00390.jpg'
filename = (os.path.basename(s))
userElement = ET.Element("annotation")
newSub = ET.SubElement(userElement, "filename")
newSub.set(filename, '')#<----- ***** 
root.insert(0, newSub)
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write(open('3.xml', 'w'), encoding = 'UTF-8')
```

The output of this will return

> `<filename 00390.jpg=""/>`

Instead of

> `<filename>00390.jpg</filename>`

This is because at (*) you are setting an attribute value instead of a text in the XML subelement tag.

To solve your problem, replace this `newSub.set(filename, '')` with this

```
newSub.text = filename#Assigns text
root.insert(0,newSub)
#Returns this <filename>00390.jpg</filename>
```

See an example [here](https://kite.com/python/examples/3596/xml-insert-a-subelement-into-an-xml-element)

Answer (score 0):

As @mzjn has mentioned try using  [`Element.insert`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.insert) method. This allows you to specify an index on where exactly you want to insert it.

For example, to insert before 2nd element:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

#your tree
root = ET.fromstring('''
<element>
    <att1></att1>
    <att3></att3>
</element>
 ''')

#Create a new element
new = ET.Element('att2')
root.insert(1, new)  # <-----------Insert operaton
print(ET.tostring(root))

#output
"""
<root>
    <att1/>
    <att2/>#newly inserted 
    <att3/>
</root>
"""
```

**Edit:**

The [`ElementTree.write`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write) method defaults to us-ascii encoding and as such expects a file opened for writing binary:

> The output is either a string (str) or binary (bytes). This is controlled by the encoding argument. If *encoding* is `"unicode"`, the output is a string; otherwise, it’s binary. Note that this may conflict with the type of *file* if it’s an open file object; make sure you do not try to write a string to a binary stream and vice versa.

So either open the file for writing in binary mode:

```
tree.write(open('person.xml', 'wb'))
```

or open the file for writing in text mode and give `"unicode"` as *encoding*:

```
tree.write(open('person.xml', 'w'), encoding='unicode')
```

Comment: i have added my code please let me know where i am doing wrong?

Comment: Try print this `print(ET.tostring(root))` before these two lines `tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write("33.xml")` . Whats the output? Is it modified?

Comment: "unicode" option works, it added <filename/> after <annotation> but i need `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ASCII'?> <annotation> <filename>2007.jpg</filename>`

Comment: i want to add image name (2007.jpg) into their corresponding file like `<filename>2007.jpg</filename>`

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13281833/6505847) on setting the value. If filename tag appears the annotate then that means you are not setting the insert correctly. You can also create the `annoate` element first and then insert `filename` as child element to that.

Comment: not yet, as your mentioned linked only takes/sets the string which needs to be define but my requirements to takes the image name from another folder. as i have mentioned in my question.

Comment: I may be wrong; if I am, do correct me!!! Since the xml and image name files are the same you can use the `os` module to get the name of the xml and then you can use that as the value in the element.

Comment: i have updated my code in the question, i am able to get output but a bit different then the required output: Output is received: `<filename 00390.jpg=""/>`
Although output should be `<filename>00390.jpg</filename>` 
I think issue is using newSub.set() which takes 3 input argument.

Comment: See my new answer for the new problem you are having. Comment on that if you have any issues with it.